# Creating matrix of distances in R from lat & long between two dataframes

Tags: r, matrix, gps, distance, latitude-longitude

I have two dataframes each consisting of a combination of latitude, longitude, and the corresponding ID.

I'm trying to do essentially:

```
 for each_ID in df1:
     for each_ID in df2: 
          calculate distance in miles
 result_df = df1 x df2

     df=data.frame(id  = c('row1','row2','row3'), lat = c(47,57,67), long = c(-80,-80,-80))
     df2 = data.frame(id  = c('col1','col2','col3'), lat = c(47,57,67), long = c(-83,-84,-85))
```

I want to calculate the distance for every point inbetween df1 and df2.   I don't need to calculate the distances between the points in df1.   I want everything in a matrix with rows and column names of the corresponding column names.

I've looked around and I don't see an easy way of doing this.  Anyone offer some assistance?

Comment: What distance are you interested in calculating? With lat/long the haversine formula is what I have used (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) -- or do you want another distance such as Manhattan, Euclidean, etc.?

Comment: https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_measures.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `distm` function from the `geosphere` package, which by default computes the Haversine distance, but you can also precise other distance functions if you need to. By default, the distance is in meters, but you can convert it into miles by multiplying by a conversion constant.

```
library(geosphere)
res = distm(df1[c("long","lat")],df2[c("long","lat")])*0.0006213712
rownames(res) = df1$id
colnames(res) = df2$id
         col1     col2      col3
row1  141.5143 712.0616 1395.1172
row2  703.2304 150.6708  709.9512
row3 1387.6401 703.4400  135.0994
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(generator)

df1 <- data.frame(id=seq(1:10), lat=r_latitudes(10), lon=r_longitudes(10))
df2 <- data.frame(id=seq(1:10), lat=r_latitudes(10), lon=r_longitudes(10))
```

[image]

**Grab a [function](https://conservationecology.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/distance-between-two-points-in-r/) for calculating distance between longs and lats:**

```
lat_lon_dist <- function(long1, lat1, long2, lat2) {
    rad <- pi/180
    a1 <- lat1 * rad
    a2 <- long1 * rad
    b1 <- lat2 * rad
    b2 <- long2 * rad
    dlon <- b2 - a2
    dlat <- b1 - a1
    a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
    c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    R <- 6378.145
    d <- R * c
    return(d)
}
```

**Calculate all distances between data frames, and set to new data frame:**

```
distances = NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    labels = paste('DF1_long=', df1[i,3], 'DF1_lat=', df1[i,2], 'DF2_long=', df2[i,3], 'DF1_lat=', df2[i,2])
    distances[i] <- lat_lon_dist(df1[i,3], df1[i,2], df2[i,3], df2[i,2])
    }

data.frame(labels, distances)
```

[image]

There are likely more accurate distance calculations, such as those available from the [geosphere](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geosphere/geosphere.pdf) package. Not sure you want those labels in your final frame but change as needed. Also, you can convert this frame into a matrix if that's the final result you want.